# Why does Mapbox throw Error: DOMException: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, dom, mapbox-gl-js, parceljs, preact

I've had a preact-Mapbox site I've been running locally without error for a while. Then this error shows up.

```
DOMException: The operation is insecure.
```

Firefox Console says its coming from the mapbox  util.js, which says

```
        // console isn't defined in some WebWorkers, see #2558
        if (typeof console !== "undefined") console.warn(message);
        warnOnceHistory[message] = true;
```

I can't figure out what's triggering this `WarnOnce` function.
I'm not using a Service Worker or a Manifest.

The above util.js references a Mapbbox issue #2558. As far as I can tell, I haven't done anything to mess with the web worker scope.

The error code usually shows with

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

In firefox private browser, it shows the errors and doesn't load the rest of the mapbox gl functions. In Chrome, Safari and Edge, it doesn't show the error, just refuses to load the rest of the mapbox gl functions.

If you reload the page, the rest of the functions run. But for first time visitors, the page does not load.

Its a largish app, with a Material Ui Swipeable drawer, bundled with parcel.

But this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8/>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no'/>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://* blob: data:; script-src https://* 'sha256-NwPGqa9Mxa7ZIeBSPi4K97Vtt3uBWjwtJsUlZfeqG5E' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https://*; child-src blob: ; connect-src https://*;">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../icons/icon.svg" type="image/x-icon">

        <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.6.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.3.0/mapbox-gl-draw.css' type='text/css' />

        <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.6.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
        <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.2.2/mapbox-gl-draw.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jost"></link>

        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="app.js" type="module" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is one request made to heroku also.

```
export default (url) => {
        return $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: (url),
            success: function (res) {
                return res
            }
        }); 
}
```

Making it to localhost doesn't remove the error.

Any ideas on what's triggering this error are appreciated.

Comment: I just started getting "DOMException: Operation too large" on Chrome, not no Edge, on code that was running without such error for few months.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer but it might help.

I got the same error in the Firefox console. Unfortunately it was quite vague:

```
ERROR DOMException: The operation is insecure. core.js:4442
    Angular 4
    RxJS 5
    Angular 20
    RxJS 14
    Angular 15
    a scripts.js:2
    watch scripts.js:2
    a scripts.js:2
    trigger scripts.js:2
    open scripts.js:2
    handle Angular
    RxJS 17
```

I tried with the chrome console and it showed this:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

Which was more helpful in my case. Maybe it could show a more detailed error message in your case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't get that same error from Chrome. I ended up leaving the firefox error in, since I've read that its apparently supposed to be there and I couldn't find anything that prevented it. And pre-loading the mapbox connection so that the error didn't prevent the rest of the map from loading.